# What is the difference between type IIA and type 0A string theory?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry

When people study string theory the most useful models are IIA and IIB. I'm not quite sure I understand what is the difference between 0A and IIA string theory. In the type 0 case we only have bosons but how do we see that from the ground/first excited states of the theories?

Comment: On the worldsheet, type 0 theories are identical to the respective type II. Thus, the critical dimension is again ten. Also, type 0 theories are supersymmetric on the world-sheet. This is the similarity. The difference comes when performing the GSO projection. In type II you have separate GSO projections for the left and right-moving sectors, while in type 0 you have only one combined GSO projection. Type 0 theories do not have R-NS and NS-R sectors; they are not supersymmetric at the level of the spacetime (see https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/5886)